# Why is does it take so long to run this on Spark/Dataproc?

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm processing data using Spark running on a Dataproc cluster. I've tried making the cluster more powerful, adding more CPUs and disk space, but it's not helping much. I read data from BigQuery using:

```scala
Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().format("bigquery")
    .option("table","project.dataset.tablename")
    .load()
    .cache();
```

I'm using `.cache()` because I use `data` multiple times.

I've also tried using `.text()` instead of `.csv()` and it's not improved.

The only thing that has helped is reducing the number of records in the data.

What can I change to make it run faster?

```scala
data.select("column1","column2")
    .write()
    .mode("append")
    .partitionBy("column1")
    .csv("gs://bucket/folder");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many workers and masters are you using ? what is the size of the data you are processing?

Also for higher performance clusters, you should use PD-SSD disks. SSD persistent disks are designed for workloads with high rates of random IOPS which may provide large benefits to some Spark and Hadoop workloads.

also.. have you considered dataflow ? It has less start up time and it scales automatically with the volume of data, you etl process seems simple enough, is there any reason why you are using dataproc ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I was just looking into Dataflow, but still need to figure out how to get it running, never used it before. Sounds stupid, but I was more familiar with Dataproc/Spark and not at all with Dataflow/Beam so I went for Dataproc. I used 1 Master with 4 Workers, all 16 vCPUs, all with 2TB PD-SSD disks according to It's already slow with around 1GB of data. I think I'll do my best to give Dataflow a try.

Comment: Let me know how it goes ! If you ever used apache beam, it's basically that :)

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question but I have my .jar file, how do I get it into Dataflow, it's asking for a template?

Comment: You have to use specific maven goals, follow this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven - You can see how he uses mvn exec:java in order to make it run locally or on dataflow :) there should be also one other plugin/goal that you can use to create a template and push it to gcs, in order to start the future runs directly in dataflow (or via api)